# access global variable of drupal into another php files

Tags: drupal, variables, global

I want to access global variable of drupal (like user variable in
drupal) into another php files
I Create a new module for example test module.
my test module have 3 files . test.info , test.module , main.php
I want to use global variable of drupal into main.php as following code

global $user;
please guide me how can i access this drupal variable in my page?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want `main.php` to be separate from the Drupal system you'll have to [Bootstrap Drupal](http://timani.net/2010/04/bootstrap-and-include-drupal-from-outside-the-drupal-root/) in your custom file, but depending on what you're trying to do there may be an easier way.

If you're just trying to output some HTML/text without the Drupal theme then just implement a menu hook in your module and call `exit()` from your page callback. Something like this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['path/to/page'] = array(
    'title' => 'Title',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
}

function mymodule_page() {
  // You have access to the full Drupal bootstrap here as normal
  global $user;

  $content = 'Some Content';

  echo $content;

  exit();
}
```